# Multiple Parameters

Tags: ruby

I have an object that allows users to connect to HDFS. One method allows them to download data, and the other upload data. The `initialize` method looks something like this:

```
def initialize(file=nil,set=nil,action)
end
```

How can I change the way arguments are passed to be more efficient? The `action` param is required every time, but `file` and `file_set` are only required depending on the `action`. I.e., if they want to upload data they need to pass `set`, if they want to download data, they just pass `file`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 2.0 you can use [keyword parameters](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/):

```
def initialize(action, file: nil,set: nil)
  unless file.nil?
    # do stuff with file
  end
end
```

So you can call it:

```
MyClass.new(some_action)
MyClass.new(some_action, set: some_set)
MyClass.new(some_action, file: some_file)
MyClass.new(some_action, set: some_set, file: some_file)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should pass requred parameter first e.g.:

```
def initialize(action, file = nil, set = nil)
end
```

Then you may want to use hash to pass optional params:

```
def initialize(action, options = {})
end
```

The passing hash is a common way when you need to pass more than one optional parameter.
When you need to pass `file`, `set` or both you may call initialize method as follow (assume that this method is defened in the `class MyModel`):

```
MyModel.new(action, {file: ''})
MyModel.new(action, {set: ''})
MyModel.new(action, {file: '', set: ''})
```

Or when you don't want to pass any optional params, simply call:

```
MyModel.new(action)
```

In this case you will have empty options hash passed in you `initialize` method.

Comment: Well, in this case the file or set will also always be required (one of the two will have to be provided), so they aren't really options per say. See what I mean?

Comment: @GrahamJackson I have added some further explanation.

Comment: In modern Ruby, required arguments can come after optional ones.

Comment: And modern Ruby has named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Quite common is to use positional parameters when they are mandatory, and an options hash
for the rest. You just need to check action to verify given params are then present:

```
def initialize(action, opts={})
  if action == 'foo'
    raise ArgumentError, "requires either :file or :set" unless 
      ([:file, :set] & opts.keys).size == 1
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: That is old fashioned.